# Google API how do I get one variable from my result

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-api, youtube-api

I want to isolate `subscriberCount: '15'` to it's own variable but nothing I do works here is all the data I have (some censored for security reasons) please try to help me!

Code

```js
const Youtube = require("youtube-api")
    , fs = require("fs")
    , readJson = require("r-json")
    , Lien = require("lien")
    , Logger = require("bug-killer")
    , opn = require("opn")
    , prettyBytes = require("pretty-bytes")
    ;

// I downloaded the file from OAuth2 -> Download JSON
const CREDENTIALS = readJson(`${__dirname}/credentials.json`);
 
// Init lien server
let server = new Lien({
    host: "localhost"
  , port: 5000
});
 
// Authenticate
// You can access the Youtube resources via OAuth2 only.
// https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/moving_to_oauth#service_accounts
let oauth = Youtube.authenticate({
    type: "oauth"
  , client_id: CREDENTIALS.web.client_id
  , client_secret: CREDENTIALS.web.client_secret
  , redirect_url: CREDENTIALS.web.redirect_uris[0]
});
 
opn(oauth.generateAuthUrl({
    access_type: "offline"
  , scope: ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner-channel-audit https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner-channel-audit https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly"]
}));
 
// Handle oauth2 callback
server.addPage("/oauth2callback", lien => {
    Logger.log("Trying to get the token using the following code: " + lien.query.code);
    oauth.getToken(lien.query.code, (err, tokens) => {
 
        if (err) {
            lien.lien(err, 400);
            return Logger.log(err);
        }
 
        Logger.log("Got the tokens.");
 
        oauth.setCredentials(tokens);
 
        lien.end("Eyyy you logged in!");

       // var req = Youtube.videos.insert({ });
        function execute() {
        return Youtube.channels.list({
         "part": [
          "statistics"
          ],
          "mine": true,
          "prettyPrint": true
        })
        .then(function(response) {
                // Handle the results here (response.result has the parsed body).
                //console.log("Response", response);
                //console.log(typeof response.data.items);
                //console.log(response.data.items);
                //console.log(result);
                console.log(response.data.items);
                //console.log(response.statistics);
              },
              function(err) { console.error("Execute error", err); });
        }
        execute();
    });
});
```

Response From google:

```
[
  {
    kind: 'youtube#channel',
    etag: '*****',
    id: '*****',
    statistics: {
      viewCount: '506',
      subscriberCount: '15',
      hiddenSubscriberCount: false,
      videoCount: '12'
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: where are you trying to do anything?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: *nothing I do works here* ... where? where does nothing work?

Comment: I'm trying to isolate ```subscriberCount: '15'``` to one variable instead of a massive object.

Comment: where in your code did you do something that doesn't work? I can't see where that should be done, so I'm asking you to point to the line of code you want that done

Comment: ```console.log(response.data.items);``` I want just one number I have tried ```console.log(response.data.items.statistics.subscriberCount);``` but that only returns ```undefined```

Comment: `response.data.items` is an Array, by the look of your question, ... so you'd need `response.data.items[0].statistics.subscriberCount`

Comment: OH MY GOD, THANK YOU SO MUCH

Comment: @JaromandaX you should post this as the answer.

Comment: @DaImTo - no thanks, took too long to get enough info to guess the problem :p

Answer (score 0):

[Jaromanda X](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5053002/jaromanda-x) gave the solution [in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68149644/google-api-how-do-i-get-one-variable-from-my-result/68151862#comment120451245_68149644):

> `response.data.items` is an Array, by the look of your question, ... so you'd need `response.data.items[0].statistics.subscriberCount`

Comment: If you want to post a comment as an answer, the common way to do so is quote the comment (As you did), with a link to the comment and the user's profile and possibly mark the answer as a Community Wiki (you can still do so in the edit page)